# Finding the closest location from an array (iOS)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, cocoa-touch

I need to find the 20 closets stores from an `NSMutableArray` that stores `CLLocationCoordinate2D` objects and add it into another array.

Any idea of how can I do it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using [`distanceFromLocation:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocation_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CLLocation/distanceFromLocation:)? Sort the array by distance, take the first element.

PS: I am assuming you actually store `CLLocation` instances, since `CLLocationCoordinate2D` is a `struct`, not a reference type. You can construct `CLLocation` objects easily from latitude and longitude, if you really somehow manage to store non-objects in an `NSArray`.

**Edit**:

simple swift example

```
var a = [CLLocation]() // this would be your actual array
let loc = CLLocation() // this would be your current location
a.sortInPlace { (l1, l2) -> Bool in
    l1.distanceFromLocation(loc) <= l2.distanceFromLocation(loc)
}
let smallest = a.first? // this would be your closest value.
```

In Objective-C, the relevant method is [`sortUsingComparator:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableArray/sortUsingComparator:) on `NSMutableArray` like so:

```
NSMutableArray* a = [NSMutableArray new];
CLLocation* loc = [CLLocation new];
[a sortUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id  _Nonnull obj1, id  _Nonnull obj2) {
// Edit 3: verbose comparator.
    float dist1 =[(CLLocation*)obj1 distanceFromLocation:loc];
    float dist2 = [(CLLocation*)obj2 distanceFromLocation:loc];
    if (dist1 == dist2) {
        return NSOrderedSame;
    }
    else if (dist1 < dist2) {
        return NSOrderedAscending;
    }
    else {
        return NSOrderedDescending;
    }
}];

// Edit 2
CLLocation* smallest = a.firstObject;
    NSMutableArray* closest = [NSMutableArray new];
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    [closest addObject:a[i]];
}
```

Comment: Can you give me a code example for this?
BTW, I'm storing on the array objects from a custom class called `Store` (inherits from `NSObject`) that has an address (`NSString`), name (`NSString`) and geoPoint (`CLLocationCoordinate2D`).

Comment: Thanks! But I don't think I'm really understanding. Can you please post an example for finding the 20 nearest store to the user's current location from array with about 1700 stores? Thank you so much for helping!!

Comment: I did edit my answer again. But that should've been a no brainer.

Comment: But it's not from the user's current location, it's from one store to another.

Comment: I did update the answer once again to make it more verbose on what is happening.

Comment: Thank you very very much! Really appreciate that!